# Is there a "use double plus strict" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I sometimes misspell a variable name.
I'd like for JavaScript to abort and say "X is undefined" instead of assigning the value of undefined to X continuing along it's merry way.

Q: Is there a setting or something that I can do to make it more plainly visible that I've misspelled a variable name?

Comment: Maybe I could define undefined = function() { alert('Something is undefined.') }

Comment: Yeah, but in that case, you would be storing a reference to that function in the variable (and it wouldn't be called). If you made it `(function() { alert('Something is undefined.') })()`, it would be called (and the alert would happen), but it would still return `undefined` because you're not returning anything in the function.

Answer (score 3):

(Outside of ES5) Not in the language but verification tools like http://www.jslint.com/ will pick this up and can either be run at "build" time or integrated into your IDE.

Answer (score 2):

It's called [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) (as of ECMAScript 5).

```
"use strict";
```

to enable it in the current and all contained scopes.

Example:

```
​"use strict";
x = 1;​​​​
>> Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined
```

If the browser doesn't support it, it simply ignores the "use strict" string. Just use a browser that [supports strict mode (at the bottom of the table)](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/) for development to catch errors more quickly.

Comment: Hmmm..  I thought I had "use strict" in my program.  I'll have to double check now.

Comment: @Phillip Your browser needs to support it, and it only catches the errors at runtime.